# Confused with this C code

Tags: c

First I want to clear it already that this is a assignment question so i don't need exact answer or all coding .The question is of checking Pythagorean triplets for any three integer inputs .I have made the fallowing code but it says that it has an "else" without a previous "if" though I already have "if" so I am confused that why compiler is showing that wrong error ? and If I am not getting it then what exactly I am missing here .It also shows the error warning: implicit declaration of function 'elseif' ,even when I already included the library stdio.h and stlib.h ? why ? Thank you !

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, largest, large, small;
    printf("Enter a b and c: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);

    if (a^2+b^2==c^2)
    {
        printf("yes");
    }
    elseif((a^2+c^2)==b^2);
    {
        printf("yes");
    }

    elseif((c^2+b^2)==a^2);
    {
        printf("yes");

    }
    else
    {
        printf("no");

    }


}
```

Note: Even when I already told that its an assignment question and I don't need exact solution/code but just clarification regarding my confusion ,still there are people who love to down vote my question ,Don't know why :\ .I feel stack overflow is a platform to discuss code and confusion related to it regarding error or so ,so what's wrong if I discussed my assignment question code? there are people who just help me deeply in forming/understanding my code well through detailed explanations(I am thankful to all those below) and then there are people who just down vote rather being more constructive and helpful :/

Comment: Are you  sure you are giving space between else and if in elseif ?

Comment: `elseif` to `else if` and take out the `;` after `if` statement, you may rather use it after `printf ...`

Answer (score 1):

Because you have `;` here:

```
elseif((a^2+c^2)==b^2);
                      ↑
```

It's equivalent to:

```
else if((a^2+c^2)==b^2) { } 
{
        printf("yes");
} else .. //problem is here
```

Also please note that `^` is not a power as other answer mentioned.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get that how you say that there is a ";" after "if" because i don't see ";" after "if" .are you talking about "elseif" ? As i know "elseif" should have that semi colon included .

Comment: Yes and its my bad that I was perhaps confused with elif of python ,now I got that In C its else if with space not like elseif same as elif .

Answer (score 0):

a^2 doesn't raise a to the power of 2. The ^ operator calculates the exclusive or of its two operands. Use a*a instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add a space between else and if

else if(Condition)

Answer (score 0):

**Remove `;`, it indicates null statement.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, largest, large, small;
    printf("Enter a b and c: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);

    if (a*a+b*b==c*c)
    {
        printf("yes");
    }
    else if((a*a+c*c)==b*b)
    {
        printf("yes");
    }

    else if((c*c+b*b)==a*a)
    {
        printf("yes");

    }
    else
    {
        printf("no");

    }
}
```

**If you want to make your code more efficient, you can calculate `a*a`, `b*b`, `c*c` and store them in some variables and re-use it  instead of re-calculating every time.**

Answer (score 0):

**Remove ; after else if , not sure why they are..they indicate null statements**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, largest, large, small;
    printf("Enter a b and c: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);

    if (a*a+b*b==c*c)
    {
        printf("yes");
    }
    else if((a*a+c*c)==b*b)
    {
        printf("yes");
    }

    else if((c*c+b*b)==a*a)
    {
        printf("yes");

    }
    else
    {
        printf("no");

    }

}
```

**If you want to make your code more efficient , you can calculate a*a ,b*b,c*c and store them in some variables and re-use it  instead of re-calculating every time.**

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert space between

> elseif

it should  be like

> else if

2. There should be no ; after else condition

> else if()

3. a^2 doesn't raise a to the power of 2. The ^ operator calculates the exclusive or of its two operands. Use a*a instead. or you may use **pow()** function from math.h.

your code should be like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, largest, large, small;
    printf("Enter a b and c: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);

    if (a*a+b*b==c*c)
        printf("yes");
    else if((a*a+c*c)==b*b)
        printf("yes");
    else if((c*c+b*b)==a*a)
        printf("yes");
    else
        printf("no");
}
```